# How to distribute comma separated element to form a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, split, multiline

How to extract/split multi-line comment to make a new list

```
clientInfo="""James,Jose,664 New Avenue,New Orleans,Orleans,LA,8/27/200,123,jjose@gmail.com,;
  Shenna,Laureles, 288 Livinghood Heights,Brighton,Livingston,MI,2/19/75,laureles9219@yahoo.com,;
  """
 into this kind of list

 f_name = ["james","sheena"]
 l_name = ["jose","Laureles"]
 strt = ["664 New Avenue","288 Livinghood Heights"]
 cty = ["New Orleans","Brighton"]
 state = ["New Orleans","Livingston"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is always same. You could do something like this;

```
f_name = []
l_name = []
strt = []
cty = []
state = []
for client in clientData.split(";\n "):
    client_ = client.split(",")
    f_name.append(client_[0])
    l_name.append(client_[1])
    strt.append(client_[2])
    cty.append(client_[3])
    state.append(client_[4])
```

I could add some exception handling to handle the `;` at the end of your string but, leaving that to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
clientData = """James,Jose,664 New Avenue,New Orleans,Orleans,LA,8/27/200,123,jjose@gmail.com,;
  Shenna,Laureles, 288 Livinghood Heights,Brighton,Livingston,MI,2/19/75,laureles9219@yahoo.com,;
  """
data = clientData.split(";\n")

f_name = []
l_name = []
strt = []
cty = []
state = []

for data_line in data:
    data_line = data_line.strip()
    if len(data_line) >= 5:
        line_info = data_line.split(",")
        f_name.append(line_info[0].strip())
        l_name.append(line_info[1].strip())
        strt.append(line_info[2].strip())
        cty.append(line_info[3].strip())
        state.append(line_info[4].strip())

print(f_name)
print(l_name)
print(strt)
print(cty)
print(state)
```

Output:

```
['James', 'Shenna']
['Jose', 'Laureles']
['664 New Avenue', '288 Livinghood Heights']
['New Orleans', 'Brighton']
['Orleans', 'Livingston']
```

Comment: I got this error.  l_name.append(line_info[1].strip())
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>

Comment: @benjarmintia: Modified `if` condition. try with this

Comment: @benjarmintia: Please accept any 1  answer which worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `zip`.

```py
def extract(string):
  lines = string.split(";")
  split_lines = tuple(map(lambda line: line.split(","), lines))
  no_space1 = tuple(map(lambda item: item.strip(), split_lines[0]))
  no_space2 = tuple(map(lambda item: item.strip(), split_lines[1]))
  return list(zip(no_space1, no_space2))
```

This will produce

```
[('James', 'Shenna'), ('Jose', 'Laureles'), ('664 New Avenue', '288 Livinghood Heights'), ('New Orleans', 'Brighton'), ('Orleans', 'Living
ston'), ('LA', 'MI'), ('8/27/200', '2/19/75'), ('123', 'laureles9219@yahoo.com'), ('jjose@gmail.com', '')]
```

It has some tuples at the end you didn't ask for, but its relatively good. The `no_space` 1 and 2 lines are a bit repetitive, but cramming them into one line is worse in my opinion.